# Чтение данных из data ltp

Tags: порт

Здесь ([чтение/запись в LPT порт](http://www.pcports.ru/articles/5.php)) сказано, что

> Это (Data) самый толковый регистр - он позволяет нам как из программы, так и из внешнего устройства установить на его контактах лигическую 0 или 1, т.е. он двунаправленный.

Также там есть описание, как считать информацию с регистра DATA.

Внимание, вопрос: как записать информацию на DATA c внешнего устройства?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы "записать" данные в регистр Data извне, нужно подать на контакты разъема LPT какие-либо значения. Это можно сделать, подсоединив по LPT-кабелю выход с другого LPT-разъема. То есть можно взять два компьютера, соединить из по LPT-кабелю, запустить на том, и на другом код, который будет обмениваться данными по LPT: один будет писать в порт, другой - читать из порта. В качестве эксперимента можно взять и соеднить машины по Hyperterm.exe посылать туда и обратно файлы.

Comment: А нельзя как то не с компьютера, а при помощи источников питания и проводов, резисторов итп?

Comment: Можно. Но проще, быстрее и дешевле с компьютера. Либо найти какую-нибудь микросхему LPT-контроллера (или что-то вроде).

Comment: То есть нельзя соеденить какие-то регистры ( с элементом питание возможно) и подать  сигнал на компьютер?  Например для регистра status достаточно просто замкнуть его на землю и соответствующее значение изменится с 1 на 0.